# Guardar un valor en Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Quiero tomar el valor que tengo en el `TextView`, sumarlo, guardarlo y volver a repetir este proceso cada vez que se toca el botón, pero no entiendo porque no logro guardarlo.

Mi código:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b1;
    TextView tv3,tv4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("Saldo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        tv4.setText(preferences.getString("Valor", ""));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void a(View view){

        int x=200;

        String valor1=tv4.getText().toString();
        int nro1=Integer.parseInt(valor1);
        int sumar=nro1 + x;
        String resultado=String.valueOf(sumar);
        tv4.setText(resultado);

        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("Saldo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("Valor", tv4.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, arregla la vista del código, lo puedes editar la pregunta, selecionas el código y le das a el boton de encima {}

Comment: @AgustilVal tu metodo esta definido para ser llamado desde el layout con el boton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes unos pequeños fallos en el código, pero no te preocupes, te los intentaré explicar lo mejor posible:

Resulta que si quieres que cuando se pulse el botón suceda la acción de sumar y guardar, lo estas haciendo mal, ya que para que un botón se enlace con la acción se pueden hacer da varias formar:

**NOTA: si ya sabes las formas de enlazar un acción con un botón pasa al apartado de las `SharedPreferences`, justo bajo la explicación de los botones.**

**ENLAZAR UN MÉTODO A UN BOTÓN**

De esta forma tienes que crear un método en tu código `Java` y desde las propiedades del botón del apartado `XML` de `Desing`, tendrías buscar una propiedad llamada `onClick` y asignarle ahí le método que has creado. No hace falta pasarle ninguna `View`a este método como realizas tu en el método `a()`

**IMPLEMENTAR EL MÉTODO ONCLICKLISTENER**

Para hacer esto, tienes dos formas:

- En tu declaración de la clase principal añades lo siguiente e implementas los códigos necesarios:

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

      Button b1;


      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
          // Así se enlaza el botón a el método
          b1.setOnClickListener(this);

      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // Método necesario de implementar
          // Para saber que botón se pulsa en caso de tener más de uno
          switch (v.getId()){
              case R.id.b1:
                  // Añadir aquí el código que quieras que funcione cuando     se presione el botón 
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- La otra forma, es implementandolo directamente a tu botón en el método `onCreate()`:

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

      Button b1;
      TextView tv3;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btGuardar);
          // Implementación de la ación del botón
          b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  //Acciones que quieras que realice el botón
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```

Una vez sabido esto, te explico las `SharedPreferences` y entenderas porque te falla:

**SHAREDPREFERENCES**

- Para sacar un valor de las `SharedPreferences` se utiliza este código:

  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Saldo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  textview.setText(preferences.getString("Valor", "5"));

En la primera linea se declara el archivo de `SharedPreferences` al que se accederá. En este caso se llamará `Saldo`. Cuando se ejecute esta línea, en tu dispositivo Android se creará un archivo llamado `Saldo` al que accederá siempre que lo declares la primera línea, da igual en que `Activity` (pantalla) estés.

En la segunda línea estas diciendo que agregue un valor al `TextView` que se almacena con el nombre en clave `Valor` y que en caso de que la clave `Valor` no exista, se creará y su valor inicial será de `5`.

**Tu en tu app, has puesto `""`, así que NUNCA te saldrá nada ni sumará con nada y sí que ejecuta la acción, pero el valor sigue siendo `""`, es decir, nada.**

- En caso de querer guardar se ejecuta el siguiente código, como bien tienes tu en tu código:

  ```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Saldo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putString("Valor", String.valueOf(tv3.getText()));
  editor.apply();
  ```

Intenta utilizar `apply()` para guardar los datos en vez de `commit()`.

Ahora ya sabes el porque de tu error y te dejo un código de ejemplo que he realizado:

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button b1;
    TextView tv3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btGuardar);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNumero);
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Saldo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        tv3.setText(preferences.getString("Valor", "5"));
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btGuardar:
                int x = 200;

                String valor1 = (String) tv3.getText();
                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(valor1);
                int sumar = num1 + x;
                String resultado = String.valueOf(sumar);
                tv3.setText(resultado);

                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Saldo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("Valor", String.valueOf(tv3.getText()));
                editor.apply();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.victoriavicent.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/_5"
        android:id="@+id/tvNumero"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btGuardar"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/guardar"
        android:id="@+id/btGuardar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Espero que te haya quedado todo claro, pero aun así, si  necesitas cualquier cosa o no acabas de entender algo de lo que te acabo de explicar, escríbeme un comentario y te solucionare la duda.

¡¡Mucha suerte con tu app!!

Answer (score 0):

Trata de utilizar una sola instancia de `SharedPreferences`, declara una instancia global en tu clase al igual que el editor, y usa esa misma instancia para traer la información y para guardarla, con esto aseguras que estas utilizando el mismo registro de `SharedPreferences`, a veces aunque pongas el tag en tu caso 'Saldo' al ser otra instancia de shared preferences los valores no son los mismos.

Answer (score 0):

La razón es que estas llamando el método desde el boton en el layout, definiendo ejecutar el método `a(View view)`

No tienes definida la llamada del método:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/guardar"
        android:id="@+id/btGuardar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

agrega la propiedad  android:onClick="a" :

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/guardar"
        android:id="@+id/btGuardar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" 
        android:onClick="a" />
```

para llamar el método `a()` desde el Layout.

```
   public void a(View view){
...
...
```

Si llamaras el mismo método llamando el método mediante un `OnClickListener` en código, el método cambiaría a:

```
    public void a(){
...
...
```