# ¿ Cómo recordar contraseña de un edittext?

Tags: java, android, contraseña

Tengo un `editText` y cada vez que pongo contraseña y salgo de la App tengo que escribirla, había algún método para dar algún click y que se recuerde?

Comment: Puedes usar SharedPreferences. Mira este excelente tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/  y también esto en español: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/04/como-crear-actividad-preferencias-android/

Comment: En el sitio hay varias preguntas como esta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61396/guardar-valor-de-edittext-con-sharedpreferences-y-sin-necesidad-de-utilizar-un-b  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13399/guardar-un-valor-en-android/13402#13402  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16851/persistencia-de-datos-en-android/16982#16982

Comment: Si tu contraseña es en realidad información verdaderamente sensible, no se debería guardar aquí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando `SharedPreferences` podrás guardar tu contraseña, una vez el usuario la escriba correctamente una vez.
Puedes usar `SharedPreferences` de la siguiente manera para insertar los datos:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("password", "holamundo");
editor.commit();
```

Para recuperar los datos puedes hacerlo así:

```
String password = prefs.getString("password", "valorpordefecto");
```

El segundo parámetro de `getString` es un valor por defecto por si el valor de la *password* es vacío.

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado al hacer esto ya que la contraseña se estaría almacenando en claro y el SharedPreferences es accesible si el usuario tiene rooteado el teléfono por lo que podrían producirse problemas de seguridad.

Comment: +1 gracias te doy

Comment: yo usaria alguna libreria que encripta el sharedpreferences si se quiere guardar información de carácter privado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar SharedPreferences en modo privado para guardarla, y que se recupere cada vez que vuelvas a esa vista, pero ten en cuenta que de esta forma y con el teléfono rooteado, se podría ver la contraseña.

Para hacerla más segura puedes aplicar un cifrado a tu contraseña y guardarla cifrada, o mejor usar OAUTH en tu servidor.